Can not connect to Ubuntu 24.04.1 from any remote desktop software
Thank you for taking the time to read.
I first installed teamviewer on my Ubuntu server and as it did work well, with the new version I started having issues with the limit on number of users.  I use the ubuntu for a DIY NAS.  So i was looking for an alternative when I came across Rustdesk.  I ONLY NEED TO CONNECT WITHIN LOCAL NETWORK.
I attempted to install Rustdesk as a self hosted server and it did run but I still could not connect.  So I attempted to uninstall Rustdesk. And ended with sudo apt purge Rustdesk.
After completing this, I found that I could no longer connect through any remote desktop spftware to my Ubuntu nas. I can connect from Ubuntu to anything.
I have tried reloading rustdesk, reinstalling teamviewer, setting ports open, installing nomachine, etc.  I still can not get to connect to ubuntu.
Can someone please give me locations to check or how to make sure all of my default settings are back to normal

"I found that I could no longer connect through any remote desktop spftware to my Ubuntu nas." Please edit your question and list the remote desktop software you tried and the protocols, such as ssh, xrdp, vnc, sftp, sshfs, nfs, samba, etc. you tired.

You should give ssh a try. It's way more portable/supported than anything else

You can try Remmina.
Remmina-next PPA for development (next branch) Remmina packages.
You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next to your system's Software Sources.
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
 sudo apt update
 sudo app install remmina*
 

Remmina allows you to connect remotely to the Linux server, using different protocols for this, and without the need to install additional software on the client. Just by installing Remmina, remote connection to other computers that use RDP, VNC or SSH servers, among others, would be possible.
Once the installation is complete, entering the name Remmina in the search bar will give you several options, the first one is used to run it.
The connection to RDP, VNC and SSH servers should appear in the Remmina menu, just by entering the IP address and it will use the default ports for these protocols.
Creating a new connection profile allows you to create different connection profiles to connect quickly without having to enter anything.

I use x11vnc (server) and Remmina (client) plus ssh. I use iptables on the server to reject incoming vnc connections, so no one can connect to the server except from localhost. On the server I run a loop that launches a new x11vnc instance as each one closes (necessary because x11vnc is prone to crashing). I run it without encryption or a password as x11vnc -noxfixes -repeat -display :1. Then I ssh to the server from the client, tunneling port 5900, and then on the client I run Remmina connecting to localhost:5900.
I do it this way because first I don't really want to have to type a vnc password every time, and a vnc password is less secure than my ssh keys. The performance also seemed better when relying on ssh to encrypt traffic. It's also more compatible with some very basic Android vnc clients as it uses fewer vnc features.
